# Google Custom Search and a multi tenant multi domain web application

Tags: multi-tenant, google-custom-search

I'm developing an application that runs on several domains.

I want to use Google Custom Search on all of them. But GCS requires to provide the domain(s) of websites to search.

Is there any way to specify domains dynamically? In theory I can have thousands of domains, and I don't like the idea of adding all of them manually.

Answer (score 0):

Google provide a service where you can [Create a Custom Search Engine on the fly](http://www.google.co.uk/cse/tools/create_onthefly).

To use this you have to have real links on your page and not JavaScript generated links – this is so the remote service can parse your page.

```
<form name="cse" id="searchbox_demo" action="http://www.google.com/cse">
  <input type="hidden" name="cref" value="" />
  <input type="hidden" name="ie" value="utf-8" />
  <input type="hidden" name="hl" value="" />
  <input name="q" type="text" size="40" />
  <input type="submit" name="sa" value="Search" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.co.uk/cse/tools/onthefly?form=searchbox_demo&lang="></script>
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">stackoverflow</a><br />
<a href="http://serverfault.com/">serverfault</a><br />
<a href="http://superuser.com/">superuser</a>
```

Therefore you would need to use some mechanism to dynamically create your site list page (e.g. Ruby, Python, PHP, ASP, JSP etc).  From my limited experimentation it appears that the *on the fly service* aggressively cache your requests for the creation of a custom search engine based on the requesting page (I'm not sure how long the cache lasts).  It would therefore appear that you will not be able to add and drop search sites from your list very quickly.  As a workaround you could change the url that requested the custom search box for every change.